# How to avoid few links having a css class during iteration iterate

Tags: jquery

i have many links in page but few links has few specific css class attached. i want to avoid those link which has **.noclass** attached.

i know this way i can iterate in all the links of page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(index) {
        alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
    });
});
```

now tell me when i am iterating all links in page then how could mention to avoid few links which has **.noclass** attached ?

anyone can help me with example. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a:not(".noclass")').each(function(index) {
        alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
    });
});
```